# Dynamically creating Object literal

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to **dinamically add an object** named "geometry" and it's attributes "x" and "y", inside of an array of objects named "features". Assume the for **loop runs N** times instead of just 2.
The final structure I want to achieve is this:

```
{
  "type": "features",
  "features": [{
      "geometry": {
          "x": -8.895197546558027,
          "y": 38.52577703769191
      }
  },
  {
      "geometry": {
          "x": -8.877264297084386,
          "y": 38.53907316236277
      }
  }]
}
```

With the code I have I get the error - "Cannot set property 'geometry' of undefined".

```
function makeOrders(){
    try {
        var orders = { "type": "features" };
        orders.features = [{}];
        for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
            orders.features[i].geometry = {};
            orders.features[i].geometry.x = "value_here";
            orders.features[i].geometry.y = "other_value_here";
        }
        console.log(orders);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be [confusing JSON with JavaScript](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Indeed. I was calling this a JSON object while this is infact an Object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> orders.features = [{}];
> ```

`features` is an array. The value (initially) at index `0` is an empty object.

That is the **only** value in it.

So when `i` becomes `1` you are trying to set properties on `undefined` instead of an object.

Don't initialize the array with an empty object. Add an object to the array when you need to:

```
for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    orders.features[i] = {};
```

… which means you won't need the empty object in the array before you start:

```
orders.features = [];
for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
```

… but there's really no need to repeatedly access the index of the array and modify the object.

Just create the object with all the data in it, and then `push` it onto the end of the array:

```
    orders.features = [];
    for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
        const object = {
            geometry: {
                x: "value_here",
                y: "other_value_here"
            }
        };
        orders.features.push(object);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand my mistake.